# What should I do with the X11 Security folder after upgrade to Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina, x11

I updated my mac to 10.15 Catalina recently. 
After update, I notice a Security Folder land on my Desktop.

I moved it to trash but I can't seem to delete it.

I've been stuck with this file in my trash for a week now.

[image]

Every-time, I tried, I got this

[image]

How do I safely get rid of it ?

Comment: Almost the same question but I can't flag it because of the bounty: [Catalina Upgrade Cannot Delete Relocated Items](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371980/catalina-upgrade-cannot-delete-relocated-items)

Answer (score 10):

I am surprised that no one has answered it.

If XQuartz was installed prior to installing Catalina then this X11 folder will exist. Uninstall your version of XQuartz using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/pwnsdx/d127873e24cef159d4d603accaf37ee4#file-gistfile1-txt) (ideally before upgrading macOS). However, you have already upgraded to Catalina so the X11 shortcut folder can't be deleted as it appears in your desktop as a [relocated item](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/a-relocated-items-folder-upgrading-macos-mac-mchl8ae423a3/mac). If you want to know more, you can check the pdf folder too.

> You can find the Relocated Items folder in the Shared folder within
>   the User folder. The PDF document in the Relocated Items folder
>   explains what to do with files placed in this folder.

Here is a solution that you can do on your side:

1. Reboot and go to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> recovery mode
2. disable SIP by `csrutil disable`
3. Reboot to normal mode and delete that folder, empty trash
4. Reboot and go to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> recovery mode
5. re-enable SIP by `csrutil enable`
6. Reboot to normal mode

Comment: Replace 2 - 5 with: Open Terminal and enter `rm -rd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD\ -\ Data/Users/bheng/.Trash/Security` or **(more secure!)** navigate to your trash: `cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD\ -\ Data/Users/bheng/.Trash`, list folder content and remove `rm -rd Security`. Replace `Macintosh\ HD\` accordingly if you renamed your main volume.

Comment: Ooops: `rm -r ...` is sufficient because -r implies -d

Comment: Having SIP off _really_ isn't such a gaping security risk that having it off for the duration of one quick reboot is going to cause anyone any problems. I think I prefer the listed answer because it allows the user to understand what's going on—you changed a setting that allows you to delete any file, deleted the file the "normal" way, and changed the setting back. However, doing it all from Terminal's recovery mode may be faster if you know how to use the Terminal.